# Why OpenGL use float to define the level of anisotropic filtering?

Tags: opengl, types, filtering

The whole question is in the title.

I really wonder why this extension uses float type instead of int. I know if you use an arbitrary value, it'll work until you don't pass the max level. But I always thought this value should be an integer of multiple of 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is no reason not to use a float. The anisotropy more or less represents the *aspect ratio* of the pixel (or filter) footprint in texture space. (In the most general case of a perspective projection, the pixel footprint would be a trapezoid in texture space, and a single aspect ratio will only be an approximation as if it were an parallelogram, but it is good enough in practice.) So a non-integral value for the anisotropy value is mathematically completely sane.

The [`GL_EXT_texutre_filter_anisotropic`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic.txt) complelely leaves open the actual implementation details to the implementor:

> The particular scheme for anisotropic texture filtering is
>        implementation dependent.  Additionally, implementations are free
>        to consider the current texture minification and magnification modes
>        to control the specifics of the anisotropic filtering scheme used.

So actually one *could* come up with a implementation where a fractional aniso setting could make a difference.

> But I always thought this value should be an integer of multiple of 2.

In practice, most GPUs do use some scheme where the limit actually is a *power* of two. If you have an aniso factor `x=2^i` and would access mipmap level `m`, the filter can basically take `x` samples from (higher resolution) mipmap level `m-i` instead.

Also note that it is explicitly allowed to set or query the aniso settings via `gl[Get]TexParameteri*()`, so you actually can use completely integer-based settings in your code and pretend that the float parameter simply doesn't exist.

Comment: It should be noted that even Vulkan uses a floating-point anisotropy, though Metal and D3D do not. But those two APIs don't require the integer to be a power of two.

Comment: I was thinking about mathematical reason, but I was unsure because of multiple engines which don't let you use other value than 2x, 4x, 8x, ...